# Skip specific lines in re-search-forward

Tags: search

Consider something like:

```
(while (re-search-forward "Pattern" nil t)
(replace-match "replace"))
```

How can I skip all lines that contain "Skip" from this replace search? I.e. Pattern should only be replaced in such lines that doesn't contain "Skip".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```el
(defun foo (old new out)
  "Replace matches for regexp OLD by string NEW, except in lines with string OUT."
  (while (re-search-forward old nil t)
    (unless (save-match-data
              (save-excursion 
                (forward-line 0)
                (re-search-forward out (line-end-position) 'NOERROR)))
      (replace-match new))))
```

Then use `(foo OLD NEW "Skip")`, for whatever values of `OLD` and `NEW` you want.

Add args to `replace-match` if you don't want the automatic case-sensitivity behavior provided or if you want a literal string replacement.

Comment: @student, see `C-h i g (elisp)Backquote`

Comment: Btw. What does the , mean in front of skip?

Comment: @phils already pointed you to info about backquote + comma syntax. See (elisp) [Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).

Comment: As `out` isn't used, I can't see how this solution works. What am I missing?

Comment: @BerenddeBoer: Sorry. Should be OK now. I left a literal `"Skip"` in place of `OUT`.